# Using Invitable friends with phonegap facebook plugin

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am aware that invitable friends (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.0) requires canvas and category game. And I have also requested for user_friends permission on initial approval of the user. I have done all that and when I use /me/invitablefriends in graph api it returns the desired results. But when I try to do the same with facebook plugin in phonegap I get the following error. "The operation couldn't be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

```
$("#invitefriends").click(function() {
    facebookConnectPlugin.api("me/invitable_friends", ["user_friends"], function (response) {
         alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    }, function (error) {
         alert("error "+error);
    });
});
```

Comment: My guess would be that it should look something like: `facebookConnectPlugin.api("me/invitable_friends", function (`

Comment: well i had my doubts too. So i tried that too since I am new to this but nope didn't work. It doesn't give any error though. It just doesn't return anything

Comment: You need to remove the `, ["user_friends"]` part

Comment: I have already tried that like I said in my above comment. It doesn't return any error or anything else if I do that

Answer (score 0):

I had used the below code to get the user's invitable friends.See if this helps :
facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me/friends?fields=id,name,picture',["public_profile","user_friends"],